# Random interval upwards counter

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm currently using a jQuery plugin for counting upwards. However, I want this to be a bit more random, simulating number of downloads. For now, the counter counts upwards every 1 seconds, but I want it to be more random every time it ticks. (range from 1sec to 4sec)

I'm currently using: [countdown](http://code.google.com/p/jquery-countdown/) together with [counter](http://blog.sophilabs.com/2012/08/jquery-counter-plugin/).

Any suggestions on how I can do this? My code looks like:

```
<script>
    $('#custom').addClass('counter-analog').counter({
        initial: '5.351.487.124',
        direction: 'up',
        interval: '2000',
        format: '9.999.999.999',
        stop: '9999999999',
    });
</script>
```

Comment: What you want can't be done without hacking the code yourself, it would have to accept `interval` as a function and use `setTimeout()` for a better flexibility.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is my take on an easy random counter:

http://jsfiddle.net/jRqAy/

```
var count = 55555;
function tick(){
    count += Math.round(Math.random()*5);
    $('span').text(count);
    setTimeout(tick,Math.round(1000+Math.random()*2000));
}
tick();
​
```

Comment: Thanks, looks like i gonna use this as a base for my development and just develop my own plugin.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$('#custom').addClass('counter-analog').counter({
    initial: '5.351.487.124',
    direction: 'up',
    interval: (Math.random()*3+1) * 1000,
    format: '9.999.999.999',
    stop: '9999999999',
});
```

`(Math.random()*3+1) * 1000` Generates a random number between `1` and `4`, then multiplies it with `1000`, to get a (random) delay in seconds.

---

**However**, this will only set a random interval at declaration as Andy mentioned in the comments.

It doesn't look like the counter has a `tick` event, so if you really wants to use that counter, you will probably have to edit the plugin's code.

Comment: But this would only set the interval to a random value once at initialization time, instead of randomizing at each tick.